# Cannot save HTML in normal text field with Core Service

Tags: core-service

I want to save content with HTML tags in a normal text field with the Core Service.  It works for an RTF field type, but the normal field type throws this exception:

> XML validation error. Reason: The element
>   'uuid:9825cfbb-ca50-4619-91ee-4d2ff2eb216e:reference' cannot contain
>   child element 'uuid:9825cfbb-ca50-4619-91ee-4d2ff2eb216e:b' because
>   the parent element's content model is text only.

```
<referenced-text xmlns=\"uuid:9825cfbb-ca50-4619-91ee-4d2ff2eb216e\">
  <quote><p>this is RTF...Imagination is more important than knowledge</p></quote>
  <reference><b>Normal text field...Fails...A. Author again</b></reference>
</referenced-text>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to HTML Encode the text before you save it and HTML Decode when you retrieve it

Answer (score 4):

If you can consider your HTML fragment as an XML, you may **also** use the CDATA in addition to what Eric has suggested. You may use following codeto get an idea *(There may be better implementation possible)*:

```
        private static void CDatafyXMLNode(XmlDocument doc, XmlNode thenode)
        {
            XmlNode cdata_node = doc.CreateCDataSection(thenode.InnerXml);
            thenode.RemoveAll();
            thenode.AppendChild(cdata_node);
        }

        public static string StripCdata(string input)
        {
            if (input == null)
                return String.Empty;

            String output = input;

            if (input.IndexOf("<![CDATA[") == 0)
            {
                output = input.Substring(9, input.Length - 9);
                if (output.IndexOf("]]>") == output.Length - 3)
                    output = output.Substring(0, output.Length - 3);
            }

            return output;
        }
```

Performance wise it would be almost similar to what HTML Encode/Decode does (or it may be better not sure though) but one advantage it provides is the Simplicity and readability while debugging or saving.